# How to print a web page in ion-view

Tags: angularjs, pdf, printing, ionic-framework

I am using [Ionic Framework](http://ionicframework.com/) for my web application. Each page is displayed using ion-view. I want to print graph (or save it as pdf).

Here is my code,

```
<ion-view title="Report">
<ion-nav-buttons side="right">
    <button menu-toggle="left"class="button button-icon icon ion-navicon"></button>
</ion-nav-buttons>
<ion-content class="has-header">
  <b style="padding:10px;">Patient Background Report</b>
    <div class="text-center item"><canvas id="line" class="chart chart-line" data="agedata" colours="colours"labels="labels" legend="true" series="series" click="onClick">
        </canvas>
        <b>Age</b>
    </div>
    <a href="javascript:window.print()" class="button button-success" style="margin-bottom:20px;">Print</a>
</ion-content>
```

I using Chrome-browser. When I click on print button , it returns

> "print preview failed".

How to print this page?

Comment: http://forum.ionicframework.com/t/print-html-file-in-ionic-framework-using-cordova/10597/3

Comment: I am using Ionic for my web app, not android app@MarkVeenstra

Answer (score 0):

I was able to get my Ionic app to print by adding the following CSS:

```
@media print {
  .scroll-content {
    position: relative;
  }

  .pane {
    position: initial;
  }
}
```

Don't ask me why that works; I just know that it works for me, and I hope it also helps someone else!

Answer (score 0):

I know that i might be a little bit late to the party but I hope that this would help others in future.

**The solution for this problem is to overwrite default ionic components styling.**

In defaults, some properties could broke our print preview like: **position, height, overflow**.

It's a must to remember that for printing:

- `height: 100%`,
- `position: fixed/absolute/relative` (in some cases),
- `overflow: hidden`,

**are 'the last nail in the coffin'.**

None of container should have them set.

For position you can use static, for `height` use `fixed values` or just leave an `auto` option. Always remember to set `overflow: visible`. Otherwise the thing we want to print could be hidden.

You can also read my short article in order to have a more in depth knowledge on printing ionic based applications: http://blog.primemodule.com/print-style-sheets-in-ionic-framework/